# How to deal with a collection nested in a RelationalModel?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-relational

I use [Backbone-Relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) to create a complex hierarchy of models, the code looks like this:

```
var ModelA = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        console.log('model a initialized!')
    }
});

var CollectionA = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: ModelA
});

var ModelB = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    relations: [{
        type: Backbone.HasMany,
        key: 'Collection',
        collectionType: CollectionA
    }]
});

var data = new ModelB({
    name: 'ModelB',
    Collection: [{
        name: 'ModelA-1'
    }, {
        name: 'ModelA-2'
    }]
});

console.log(data.get('Collection').at(0) instanceof ModelA); // false
console.log(data.get('Collection').at(0) instanceof ModelB); // true
console.log(JSON.stringify(data.toJSON())); 
// {"name":"ModelB","Collection":[{"name":"ModelA-1","Collection":[]},{"name":"ModelA-2","Collection":[]}]}
```

As you see, even though `ModelB` is successfully created, `initialize()` of `ModelA` isn't called. Checking the types proves that the objects inside the collection are not `ModelA`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two changes necessary: make `ModelA` a `RelationalModel` (and not just a standard one), and tell `ModelB` that `ModelA` is its `relatedModel`, like this:

```
var ModelA = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        console.log('model a initialized!')
    }
});
...

var ModelB = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    relations: [{
        type: Backbone.HasMany,
        relatedModel: 'ModelA',
        key: 'Collection',
        collectionType: CollectionA
    }]
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hex0dxnL/).